# Prove that $\text{tr}(((A+B)^T(A+B))^{1/2}) \leq \text{tr}((A^TA)^{1/2}) + \text{tr}((B^TB)^{1/2})$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality, trace, nuclear-norm

I'm trying to show that the nuclear norm (sum of singular values of the matrix) is actually a valid matrix norm. I know that

$$\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \sigma_i(A) = \text{tr}((A^TA)^{1/2})$$

So now what is left to prove is triangle inequality
$$\text{tr}(((A+B)^T(A+B))^{1/2}) \leq \text{tr}((A^TA)^{1/2}) + \text{tr}((B^TB)^{1/2}) \quad \forall A,B\in M_{n\times n}(\mathbf{R})$$

Which is what I'm currently stuck at. Any help would be appreciated.

**UPD.** What vector norm the matrix norm $\text{tr}((A^TA)^{1/2})$ is associated to?

Comment: $\langle A,B\rangle = \operatorname{Tr}(B^TA)$ is an inner product so $\sqrt{\langle\cdot, \cdot\rangle}$ is a norm. The triangle inequality follows from Cauchy-Schwarz.

Comment: @mechanodroid would you please elaborate more on that? What is $\sqrt{(\cdot, \cdot)}$ and why is it norm? How does the inequality in question follows from CSI? Also I added an update to the question -- would be interesting to know the vector norm this matrix norm is associated to.

Answer (score 4):

The quantity $\|A\| = \sqrt{\langle A,A\rangle} = \operatorname{Tr}(A^TA)^{1/2}$ is a norm.

If you agree that $\langle A,B\rangle = \operatorname{Tr}(B^TA)$ is an inner product, then this inner product obeys the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality $|\langle A,B\rangle| \le \|A\|\|B\|$.

Therefore

\begin{align}
\|A+B\|^2 &= \langle A+B, A+B\rangle \\
&= \langle A,A\rangle + \langle A,B\rangle  + \langle B,A\rangle  + \langle B,B\rangle \\
&=\|A\|^2 + 2\langle A,B\rangle + \|B\|^2\\
&\le \|A\|^2 + 2|\langle A,B\rangle| + \|B\|^2\\
&\le \|A\|^2 + 2\|A\|\|B\| + \|B\|^2\\
&= (\|A\| + \|B\|)^2
\end{align}
so $\|A+B\| \le \|A\| + \|B\|$.

This matrix norm is not associated with any vector norm because for the identity matrix we have $\|I\| = \sqrt{n}$, and induced norms must satisfy $\|I\| = 1$.

---

The above discussion was for the norm $\|A\|_2 = [\operatorname{Tr}(A^TA)]^{1/2}$. This is about the norm $\|A\|_1 = \operatorname{Tr}[(A^TA)^{1/2}] =  \operatorname{Tr}|A|$ where $|A| = (A^TA)^{1/2}$.

Lemma $1$

> For any matrix $A$ and two orthonormal bases $E = \{e_1, \ldots, e_n\}$ and $F = \{f_1, \ldots, f_n\}$ we have
>   $$\sum_{i=1}^n \|Ae_i\|^2 = \sum_{i=1}^n \|Af_i\|^2$$
>   In particular we have $\|A\|_2^2 = \sum_{i=1}^n \|Ae_i\|^2$.

Proof.

$$\sum_{i=1}^n \|Ae_i\|^2 = \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n |\langle Ae_i, f_j\rangle|^2 =  \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n |\langle e_i, A^Tf_j\rangle|^2 = \sum_{j=1}^n \|A^Tf_j\|^2$$

Applying this to $F$ and $F$ gives $\sum_{j=1}^n \|Af_j\|^2 = \sum_{j=1}^n \|A^Tf_j\|^2$ which completes the proof.

Let $G = \{g_1, \ldots, g_n\}$ be the orthonormal basis in which $A^TA$ diagonalizes with $A^TAg_i = \lambda g_i$. We have $$\|A\|_2^2 = \operatorname{Tr}(A^TA) = \sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i = \sum_{i=1}^n \langle A^TAg_i, g_i\rangle = \sum_{i=1}^n \|Ag_i\|^2$$

Lemma $2$

> For any positive matrix $A$ and two orthonormal bases $E = \{e_1, \ldots, e_n\}$ and $F = \{f_1, \ldots, f_n\}$ we have
>   $$\sum_{i=1}^n \langle Ae_i, e_i\rangle = \sum_{i=1}^n \langle Af_i, f_i\rangle $$
>   In particular, for any matrix $A$ we have $\|A\|_1 = \sum_{i=1}^n \langle |A|e_i, e_i\rangle = \||A|^{1/2}\|_2^2$.

Proof.

It follows from Lemma $1$:

$$\sum_{i=1}^n \langle Ae_i, e_i\rangle = \sum_{i=1}^n \|A^{1/2}e_i\|^2 = \sum_{i=1}^n \|A^{1/2}f_i\|^2 = \sum_{i=1}^n \langle Af_i, f_i\rangle$$

Let $G = \{g_1, \ldots, g_n\}$ be the orthonormal basis in which $|A|$ diagonalizes with $|A|g_i = \lambda_i g_i$. We have
$$\|A\|_1 = \operatorname{Tr}|A| = \sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i = \sum_{i=1}^n \langle |A|g_i, g_i\rangle = \sum_{i=1}^n \||A|^{1/2}g_i\|^2 = \||A|^{1/2}\|_2^2$$

To prove the triangle inequality for $\|\cdot\|_1$ for the matrices $A$ and $B$, let $A = V|A|$, $B = W|B|$ and $A+B = U|A+B|$ be the respective polar decompositions, with $V,W,U$ unitary.

For any orthonormal basis $\{e_1,\ldots, e_n\}$ we have

\begin{align}
\|A+B\|_1 &= \sum_{i=1}^n \langle |A+B|e_i, e_i\rangle\\
&= \sum_{i=1}^n \langle U^*(A+B)e_i, e_i\rangle\\
&= \sum_{i=1}^n \langle (A+B)e_i, Ue_i\rangle\\
&= \sum_{i=1}^n \Big(\langle Ae_i, Ue_i\rangle + \langle Be_i, Ue_i\rangle\Big)\\
&= \sum_{i=1}^n \Big(\langle V|A|e_i, Ue_i\rangle + \langle W|B|e_i, Ue_i\rangle\Big)\\
&= \sum_{i=1}^n \Big(\langle |A|e_i, V^*Ue_i\rangle + \langle |B|e_i, W^*Ue_i\rangle\Big)\\
&= \sum_{i=1}^n \Big(\langle |A|^{1/2}e_i, |A|^{1/2}V^*Ue_i\rangle + \langle |B|^{1/2}e_i, |B|^{1/2}W^*Ue_i\rangle\Big)\\
&\le \left(\sum_{i=1}^n \||A|^{1/2}e_i\|^2\right)^{1/2}\left(\sum_{i=1}^n\||A|^{1/2}V^*Ue_i\|^2\right)^{1/2} + \left(\sum_{i=1}^n \||B|^{1/2}e_i\|^2\right)^{1/2}\left(\sum_{i=1}^n\||B|^{1/2}W^*Ue_i\|^2\right)^{1/2}\\
&= \||A|^{1/2}\|_2^2 + \||B|^{1/2}\|_2^2\\
&= \|A\|_1 + \|B\|_1
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Could you please clarify if the norm mentioned in the first line is the trace of sqrt or sqrt of the trace? In my question I asked about the first variant, although you seem to mean the latter one.

Comment: @Swistack Yeah, I completely misunderstood the question. Have a look now, I have added a proof for the norm you originally intended.

Comment: thank you! I read your solution, but there still seems to be a mistake or misunderstanding. For example, you claim that $Tr(|A|)$ is sum of $\lambda_i$, but since $\lambda_i$ are eigenvalues of $A^TA$ and $|A| = (A^TA)^{1/2}$, then something seems to be wrong. Did you mean $\lambda_i$  to be the eigenvalues of |A|?

Comment: @Swistack Yes, $\lambda_i$ should be the eigenvalues of $|A|$, thanks for pointing out.

Comment: @mechnodroid Thanks! Now it's much more clear. Do you know if this matrix norm is induced by any vector norm?

Comment: @Swistack There was another error here. $\|\cdot\|_2$ norm of unitary operators is $\|U\|_2 = \sqrt{\operatorname{Tr}(U^*U)} = \sqrt{n}$, and not $1$. However, for an orthonormal basis $\{e_1, \ldots, e_n\}$ we have
$$\|AU\|_2^2 = \sum_{i=1}^n \|AUe_i\|^2 = \|A\|_2^2$$
because then $\{Ue_1, \ldots, Ue_n\}$ is also an orthonormal basis.

Comment: And again, $\|\cdot\|_1$ is not induced by any vector norm because $\|I\|_1 = \operatorname{Tr}|I| = \operatorname{Tr}I = n$.

Answer (score 1):

By padding the matrices with zeroes, we may assume that they are square. For any real square matrix $X$, let $X=USV^T$ be its singular value decomposition. Since $S$ is a nonnegative diagonal matrix and the diagonal entries of every real orthogonal matrix $W$ are bounded above by $1$, we have $\operatorname{tr}(S)=\max_{W^TW=I}\operatorname{tr}(SW)$. In turn, we have the following characterisation of the nuclear norm:
$$
\|X\|:=\operatorname{tr}\left((X^TX)^{1/2}\right)
=\operatorname{tr}(S)
=\max_{W^TW=I}\operatorname{tr}(SW)
=\max_{Q^TQ=I}\operatorname{tr}(XQ).
$$
Now the triangle inequality follows directly:
$$
\|A+B\|
=\max_{Q^TQ=I}\operatorname{tr}\left((A+B)Q\right)
\le\max_{Q^TQ=I}\operatorname{tr}\left(AQ\right)
+\max_{Q^TQ=I}\operatorname{tr}\left(BQ\right)
=\|A\|+\|B\|.
$$

Comment: Oh, I thought this was a new question, but actually someone bumped it up.